# How to obtain a dense ground truth image for depth prediction in kitti dataset?

Tags: dataset, heatmap, depth, estimation, kitti

For example let's say that this is the input image:

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bafpu.jpg)

This is the original ground truth downloaded:

[GT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttFnS.png)

But in all the papers they show something like this:

[heat map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP7bo.png)

How can I obtain the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to obtain a dense depth map, you need to run a depth inpainting/depth completion method on the Lidar data, which is the ground truth data you downloaded.

I suggest you to take a look at the following:

https://github.com/balcilar/DenseDepthMap

https://gist.github.com/ialhashim/be6235489a9c43c6d240e8331836586a

Also the works under the KITTI Depth Completion Benchmark could be helpful:

http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_depth.php?benchmark=depth_completion

Comment: I'd like to point you to my codebase as well
https://github.com/soulslicer/kitti_depthmap

Comment: The issue with balcilar's code is that it doesnt handle parallax errors well. Also, that code is written in Matlab, and we all know what a miserable language that is. My code is in Python/C++ hence is fast, and easy to integrate into your ML pipeline

Comment: @raaj, what is the `utils_lib` package that you're importing in your code in `testing.py`?